# Quando teve e quando terá uma eleição para moderadores?

Tags: debate

Quando teve e quando terá uma eleição para moderadores? esta vendo as medalhas e vi que existe duas medalhas (`eleição`,`constituinte`) relacionadas a eleição (`Visitou uma eleição durante qualquer fase de uma eleição ativa e tem reputação suficiente para votar`) de moderadores porem ninguém as ganhou ainda porem já vi que existe moderadores no SOpt, como isso é possível?

Answer (score 11):

> Esta resposta ficou obsoleta, ver a [resposta do Victor](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3789) abaixo.

Enquanto o site está em beta, os moderadores (eu e o utluiz) são indicados pela Stack Exchange. Assim que o site sair do beta (o que deve ocorrer em breve, mas não se sabe quando exatamente), haverá eleições diretas para nos substituir.

Comment: Espero que para vos manter!

Comment: Para lhes substituir ou para aumentar a quantidade de moderadores? Você serão destituídos? Caso sim, poderão se candidatar para reeleição? Fiquei chocado :X

Comment: @Math Na primeira eleição os pro-tems não são mantidos. Tem que se candidatar de novo, se quiserem continuar como mods.

Comment: @Gabe valeu pela informação, até então eu achava que eram mantidos.

Comment: @Math A ideia é que a gente não pode dar um "cargo vitalício" pra um usuário. No nosso caso ambos os moderadores deram muito certo e são respeitados e bem vistos pela comunidade, mas poderia não ser o caso... É por isso que eles tem que ser eleitos depois do Beta

Comment: Tem limite minimo de pontos de reputação para votar?

Answer (score 11):

De acordo com [o anúncio do Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3757/132) sobre a graduação do site:

> Agora que o site está graduado, as eleições estão programadas para começar segunda-feira, dia 1º de Junho (em 2 semanas). É a oportunidade de todos ajudarem a decidir o caminho, e o futuro, da comunidade. Serão 3 vagas abertas para moderar o site, abertas a praticamente qualquer um desde que satisfeitas algumas condições.

EDITADO: [Tivemos um problema quanto a isso.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3856/132)

Comment: Tem limite minimo de pontos de reputação para votar?

Comment: @RicardoHenrique Sim, mas o requisito mínimo é bem baixo: 150 pontos.