# Parabéns! Congratulações! Amplexos generalizados!

Tags: debate

Por muito tempo todo mundo já sabe, ou deveria saber, que o nosso site é um enorme sucesso.

O crescimento do SOpt superou qualquer expectativa. Em muito pouco tempo nós alcançamos uma comunidade engajada, dedicada e capaz de criar um dos melhores e maiores sites da rede. Isso quer dizer muito.

Quer dizer que somos uma comunidade empenhada em ajudar uns aos outros; que queremos que o site seja cada vez mais forte, e mais saudável; que programadores podem vir de qualquer lugar, e falar qualquer língua; que não deveriam haver barreiras para quem quer aprender mais sobre programação, em qualquer nível.

Os diversos problemas e desafios, que dividiram opiniões, são a manifestação concreta de que temos uma comunidade que se importa, que acredita no futuro do site e que está disposta a defender suas opiniões. Os problemas nunca vão deixar de acontecer, porque uma comunidade não pode parar de evoluir. Ela precisa se reinventar, se avaliar, se defender e se permitir mudar. Nada disso acontece sem vocês, que fizeram do SOpt o sucesso que é.

Já passou da hora, então, de vocês serem recompensados pelo excelente site que cada um ajudou a criar. É hora da comunidade ter ainda mais voz, e força, sobre o destino do site. É hora de, orgulhosamente, graduar o SOpt como o primeiro site Stack Overflow internacional, lugar que nos é de direito.

#### Parabéns pela comunidade excepcional!

## E agora?

E agora vem tudo que acompanha uma graduação. Novo layout, novos requisitos pra participar do site e eleições!

### Tudo novo

O novo layout, como vocês podem ver, já está em vigor, assim como os novos requisitos de pontuação para os privilégios no site. Isso significa que algumas pessoas perderam direitos no site. Não é exatamente o melhor presente de formatura, mas é uma parte necessária para o crescimento e estabilização da comunidade.

Graduar um site é sinal de que ele apresenta crescimento constante e que deve continuar ocorrendo indefinidamente. Isso significa que a comunidade precisa se reajustar, e se preparar, para manter a alta qualidade. Isso passa por rever as permissões. Não é muito prazeroso, mas temos certeza de que vocês têm capacidade de recuperar seus direitos!

#### Problemas...

O layout novo, acompanhado do novo perfil, é bastante coisa mudando de uma vez só. Como sempre, esse tipo de situação pode trazer à tona problemas que a gente não viu. Caso vocês avistem qualquer problema, erro, falha, bug, mistério ou outras coisas obscuras, seja no layout, tradução ou qualquer outra coisa: **postem no Meta**. Quando o site gradua há uma espécie de "plantão", com mais gente de olho nos problemas, para resolver tudo o mais rápido possível.

### Eleições

A melhor demonstração da maturidade e independência de uma comunidade - e a melhor parte da graduação! - é sua capacidade de se auto-gerenciar, escolher seus líderes e decidir seu caminho. É também uma etapa bem difícil, mas não há dúvidas de que vale o esforço.

Agora que o site está graduado, as eleições estão programadas para começar segunda-feira, dia 1º de Junho (em 2 semanas). É a oportunidade de todos ajudarem a decidir o caminho, e o futuro, da comunidade. Serão 3 vagas abertas para moderar o site, abertas a praticamente qualquer um desde que satisfeitas algumas condições.

Para saber mais, [esse post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3882/12) tem tudo que você quiser saber.

### Senta, que lá vem história

Nós estamos preparando um anúncio no nosso blog sobre a história do SOpt e a graduação. Queremos mostrar para o resto da rede o tamanho do seu sucesso, e contar um pouco sobre o que vimos e aprendemos ao longo desse ano e meio.

Seria excelente ter relatos diretos de vocês, sobre a experiência ao longo desse tempo. O que gostaram, o que não gostaram, o que esperam para o futuro... O post vai ser em Português, então não se preocupem com tradução. Quem quiser participar, basta responder aqui.

Mais uma vez, parabéns!

#### Edit Ninja:

A eleição envolve a tradução de vários textos, longos, explicando o processo, o modo de contagem dos votos, etc. É muita coisa pra traduzir em 1 semana. Como, costumeiramente, eleições só são iniciadas nas segundas-feiras, deixemos para a outra, dia 1º de junho.

<sub><sub>*Nota: Não procurem "amplexo" na Wikipédia...*</sub></sub>

Comment: O que acontecem as medalhas ganhas com moderação para quem perder os seus privilégios?

Comment: Ah e Parabéns a nós, finalmente :)

Comment: @JorgeB. As medalhas ficam, os privilégios se vão (mas voltam :))

Comment: Parabéns a nozes :)

Comment: Ontem mesmo eu estava pensando: "poxa, chegamos a 20000 perguntas e ainda não graduamos."

Comment: Graças a Deus links sublinhados e bem destacados!!

Comment: Uhul! Agora, que venha o beta do **SUpt** :D

Comment: @renan Ou do SFpt!

Comment: Parabéns aos "SOpters"* que fizeram desse site a maior referência sobre programação em PT!       (*SOpters = Users do SOpt.)

Comment: Legal, fizeram a localização da separação de milhares de acordo com o nosso, não mais igual ao dos americanos

Comment: @Math Mudou **bastante** coisa de uma só vez, pra ver se vocês ficam um tempo sem pensar no SUpt. É uma distração :D

Comment: Parabéns a todos e vamos juntos crescer esta comunidade, em pessoas e  principalmente em conteúdo! :)

Comment: Aê! Parabéns a todos nós! :)

Comment: Parabéns a todo mundo que ajudou o sopt :D

Comment: A todos os envolvidos (galerinha que conheci pessoalmente no evento e o pessoal novo que está contribuindo bastante) meus parabéns! Não deixem a tag [tag:java] morrer (contribuí umas três perguntas exóticas para chamar a galera recentemente ;)).

Comment: Para quem não sabe: http://www.dicio.com.br/amplexo/

Comment: Gabe, sobre a sua edição número 4: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/418/57

Answer (score 43):

## Apenas um de mais relatos que estão por vir

Eu descobri aqui sem querer. Estava, pra variar, procurando soluções sobre como resolver mais um dos meus problemas diários em programação e o Stack Overflow sempre foi fonte farta de informação. Aparentemente os meus problemas já foram os problemas dos outros em outras ocasiões, exceto pela tag de SVN, que sempre havia alguma pergunta avulsa que ninguém havia respondido. Aprendi a responder por lá, e consequentemente a perguntar também.

Pesquisei aqui e apareceu que entrei no dia 30 de janeiro de 2014. O site devia estar com uns dois meses. Comecei respondendo perguntas aqui e acolá das mais variadas tags, e acabei ficando mais pelas tags [c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [asp.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net), [asp.net-mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) e mais algumas outras. Responder é uma forma de devolver ao mundo o que ele me deu: uma carreira, algum conhecimento e agradecimentos. E ganhei muito mais dele do que eu podia imaginar: amigos, contatos profissionais, chances de mudar de país, risadas, piadas e oportunidades que ainda não mensurei por completo.

Várias situações inusitadas ocorreram. Já me ofereceram empregos (bem absurdos, verdade, como um em que o entrevistador queria um super-programador a preço de banana), pude conhecer alguns de vocês pessoalmente (e pretendo conhecer mais alguns outros em breve) e até **contratei alguns de vocês** (Stack Overflow em Português também é *networking*). É fantástico o poder da ferramenta como um todo, e mais fantástico ainda fazer parte do esforço que o tornou o que ela é.

Estava vendo esse layout super bonito pós-diplomação e notei uma métrica muito interessante, que é a de alcance geral. O quanto meus posts ajudaram os outros. O meu está em aproximadamente 176 mil pessoas. Cara, **isto é um número retumbante**. Não estava esperando por isso. A minha contribuição aqui é isso: ajudar os outros como eu gostaria de ser ajudado. Acho que é uma excelente forma de reconhecimento.

Por fim, gostaria de dizer que aprendo muito com vocês todos os dias. Não apenas em conhecimento. Aprendo a ser mais paciente, mais acessível, a ser sábio, a entender uma dúvida e a atender como eu gostaria de ser atendido, a ter virtude e a ser simples. Não é fácil. Tem dias que acordo super azedo e de mal com a vida. Tem dias que me aborreço de montão, mas é tudo lição. Tudo precisa ser ponderado. Quando alguém me agradece por ter desemperrado o problema dela, vejo que tudo valeu a pena, afinal.

Um "muito obrigado" já é uma excelente recompensa das pessoas. Vale mais que muito *upvote* e pergunta aceita (que são legais, mas nada comparado ao contato humano). É isto que vou levar pra todo o sempre.

---

**UPDATE**

Tinha prometido que faria uma atualização deste relato tão logo eu recebesse algumas respostas. Agora que recebi, posso fazer sobre elas.

Tentei aplicar meu currículo para trabalhar para o Forté Group (Chicago), como indicação do Luiz Ricardo (@utluiz). Como ele aplicou também para a Austrália (e passou, alvíssaras!), fui indicado no lugar dele.

Passei nas entrevistas, assinei o contrato e corri com a papelada aqui. Por pouco consegui entregar os requisitos no prazo. A resposta final saiu hoje. Infelizmente não passei, mas não vim falar sobre isso. Vim falar sobre o site, mais uma vez.

Faltou eu dizer o quanto essa ferramenta aproxima pessoas e tem o poder de mudar nossas vidas para melhor, e sempre para melhor. O mais importante é o capital humano. Confesso que eu não estava esperando passar. Tive que me mobilizar pra um monte de coisas, fiz testes super difíceis e vi que não estou tão bem quanto eu tinha imaginado. Há muita coisa pra estudar e pra me dedicar antes de tentar de novo. Acho que a próxima tentativa vai ser em 2016. Não sei ainda.

Enfim, aqui é uma experiência completa, não apenas com códigos, práticas e conhecimento, mas com auto-exame, reflexão e disciplina. Não apenas acesso a conhecimento, mas acesso ao mundo.

---

**UPDATE 2**

Em dezembro, o Forté Group ofereceu uma nova aplicação da minha inscrição para o programa de imigrantes americano (visto H1B). Em 2016, passei pela *lottery* e meu visto foi aprovado nesta época em que atualizo minha resposta. Deverei estar indo para Chicago, Illinois, em novembro.

Mais uma vez, agradeço ao Luiz Ricardo pela força, que foi essencial para que eu conseguisse. Agora vem um desafio bem grande.

Aproveitando, quem quiser que eu indique para trabalhar e viver nos EUA, é só me chamar no chat.

Enquanto este tempo passou, eu não parei. [Escrevi um curso](http://codingcraft.com.br), ampliei minhas respostas aqui e fiz muitos negócios. Contratei alguns usuários daqui, dei aulas para outros, indiquei para oportunidades profissionais. O potencial de *networking* aqui foi capaz de viabilizar a empresa que sempre quis montar: programadores remotos, desenvolvendo de onde quiserem, quando quiserem, apenas atentos aos prazos, qualidade do código e produtividade. Virei um misto de *coach*, mentor, professor, *headhunter* e empresário, e tudo isso é divertido e estimulante.

O site virou um poderoso cartão de visitas. Não consigo mais responder a todas as entrevistas de emprego que me oferecem. Até tentei uma aplicação para MVP. Quem sabe sai?

Agora sim, este relato está devidamente finalizado.

Comment: Faço das suas palavras as minhas Cigano. Também me espantei com o meu "impacto"... ~50k, bem mais do que eu esperava já que não estou mais tão ativo. Ainda que não chegue perto do meu alcance no SOEn, saber que tive um impacto em nossa comunidade é bem bacana. Também gostei muito de abrir o [perfil do Math](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3117/math) e encontrar um **[enorme botão laranja](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91557/158926)** para o perfil do Careers (Ri muito... Depois de 4 anos!)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly ainda bem que eu já arrumei meu "IN" e meu gatinho antes de você fazer propagando do meu perfil :) Sobre o botãozão, você ainda não tinha visto que sua ideia havia sido implementada?

Comment: @Math, fez bem! Preciso arrumar o meu também... Depois acertamos aquela comissão!

Comment: Muito obrigado, Cigano. E parabéns pelo impacto retumbante! :) []s

Answer (score 23):

Há pouco mais de um ano, em [Resultados de um experimento social](http://luizricardo.org/2014/02/resultados-de-um-experimento-social/), eu escrevia sobre os benefícios de ter me juntado a uma comunidade como o **Stack Overflow em Português**. Hoje digo que todos os benefícios multiplicaram-se.

O Stack Overflow me ajudou a crescer muito, ajudando e aprendendo.

Como alguns sabem, estou indo trabalhar na Austrália, mas quero reforçar dois pontos:

1. Certamente continuarei a fazer parte desta comunidade.
2. Meu sucesso na nova empreitada foi em muito graças a ajuda de todos vocês.

Só para citar um exemplo bem simples, o que eu aprendi aqui de JavaScript com o @bfavaretto, @mgibsonbr e @Sergio foi muito importante, se não essencial, para este passo na carreira.

A participação de todos faz com que nos tornemos desenvolvedores melhores, pessoas melhores e mais maduras.

**Sucesso a todos!**

Comment: Muita boa sorte na Australia. Cheers, mate! :)

Comment: Em junho vou atualizar meu relato, e o senhor será citado com louvores ;)

Comment: Boa sorte para a nova etapa @utluiz :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Matar quem? As Cheerleaders? Hehe, :p

Answer (score 22):

Eu sempre fui um ávido consumidor do conteúdo do StackOverflow (em Inglês), mas respondia pouco. Se eu fosse "chutar" um motivo, creio que sempre foi mais a falta de tempo do que de interesse. Aliás, tenho o perfil em vários sites da rede StackExchange, mas nelas também participo ativamente muito pouco. Aliás, foi só com a renovação do estilo por aqui que eu descobri que a minha melhor pergunta (tirando conteúdo aqui do SOPT) foi no site [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24961/is-learnable-a-valid-english-word).

Isso me faz pensar o que fez com que eu me tornasse tão mais ativo aqui no StackOverflow em Português. Acho que foi uma combinação de fatores. Eu comecei a acompanhar o site desde a proposta na Área 51 e confesso que não lembro como cheguei até lá!. Mas lembro que achei que valia muitíssimo a pena tentar ajudar aquelas pessoas que tinham, além das eventuais dificuldades técnicas, também dificuldade com o idioma Inglês. Pra mim isso foi uma motivação muito maior do que a reputação, embora hoje eu admito que sinto algum orgulho pela minha reputaçãozinha suada.

Logo nos primeiros meses de atividade do site ocorreu o falecimento do meu pai, e ficar mais ativo por aqui de certa forma me ajudou a atravessar aquele momento. Curiosamente, isso se tornou facilmente um grande vício, a ponto de meses depois eu ter que me policiar para não gastar tempo demais por aqui. O SOPT estava concorrendo deslealmente com as tarefas do meu doutorado (lembrei porque eu era tão pouco ativo nos demais sites da rede... hahaha).

Eu também tenho um carinho especial pela minha participação no Meta. Foi muito edificante participar da construção de uma comunidade (foi a minha primeira experiência nesse formato). Sim, eu sei que ela ainda está em construção, mas eu lembro das discussões iniciais sobre o que é ou não escopo, sobre "nós não sermos o SOEN", e sobre como nos entendemos conversando. Isso pra mim significa muito mais do que aquele número que é a reputação. A reputação que eu tenho com os colegas daqui, pessoas que as vezes eu só conheço pelo nome (ou apelido!), mas de quem sei muito a respeito profissionalmente e também (em muitos aspectos) pessoalmente.

Enfim, foi bacana e continua sendo. Vamo que vamo. :)

Comment: O negócio é marcar uma cerveja agora, hein? Amplexos!

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Tá mesmo na hora de mais um encontro do SOPT! :)

Comment: Desta vez mais informal, por favor. Dia tal, hora tal, bar tal. Bem mais fácil. Vamos usar tecnologia. WhatsApp é uma delas. Facebook também. Vamos espanar o tédio!

Comment: @Math Nomes de idiomas e nacionalidades não precisam de inicial maiúscula em português

Comment: @bfavaretto eu comecei a editar por causa de dois erros de digitação na verdade, daí como tava com a mão na massa resolvi continuar a editar e deu nisso :) Acha melhor desfazer?

Comment: @Math valeu a intenção:)

Comment: Valeu pela edição, @Math. :)

Comment: _" isso se tornou facilmente um grande vício"_ - aplica-se bem a mim e a outros tantos por aqui :)

Answer (score 20):

## O SOpt me encanta

Em que outro lugar poderíamos reunir tanta gente qualificada, gabaritada, experiente e que fossem pessoas tão bacanas como as que temos aqui?

É muito legal chegar ao trabalho/em casa, abrir o SOpt e ver que muitos tiveram um dos vários problemas resolvidos. E o melhor, em português. E é mais legal ainda, ver que isso se repete todos os dias, até mesmo nos feriados.
Por isso, eu digo: O SOpt me encanta.

---

## O SOpt me ensina

É muito legal quando alguém nos dá em que direção devemos seguir para 'desatar o nó' depois que passamos horas quebrando a cabeça com um problema.
Jamais participei de uma comunidade onde as pessoas me ajudassem tanto igual vocês me ajudam aqui no SOpt.

Mas, o aprendizado vai muito além das perguntas que nós fazemos.
Quando abrimos o link de uma pergunta recém criada, apenas para certificarmos de que está tudo 'nos conformes', nós aprendemos algo novo.

---

## O SOpt me inspira

Aqui, eu ensinei algumas coisas, aprendi várias outras e fiz amizades com pessoas que eu nunca vi na vida. E outras, que nem são tão pessoas assim. kkkk
Quem imaginou que eu iria conversar com o [ícone do Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/7210)? Ou então, que eu [falaria com um pássaro que veste uma camisa bem legal do SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3117)? Jamais imaginei que eu fosse conversar com o [spider-porco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/12)! Eu ficaria falando de um por um, até o contador de caracteres exigir que os devs façam com que ele consiga contar até a reputação do [bigown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101).

Por fim, faltam palavras para descrever o quanto o SOpt é importante para mim. Mas, tenho certeza que vocês entendem o que quero dizer. :D

Answer (score 20):

Acho que estou um pouco atrasado para responder (ou não!), mas de qualquer forma não poderia perder esta oportunidade de agradecer a todo o pessoal do SOpt pelas (tantas) vezes que me ajudaram. E realmente não foram poucas!

Imaginem um adolescente com conhecimento básico, básico mesmo, ingressando no mundo da programação no seu primeiro emprego. Esse sou eu.

Me lembro que encontrei por acaso o SOpt, no meu segundo dia de emprego. Eu estava (completamente) perdido, a cada linha de código que me deparava precisava fazer uma pesquisa no Google, pra saber o significado daquilo, a utilidade daquele outro. E foi numa dessas pesquisas que achei o site.

Já havia visto outros sites e fóruns destinados a programadores, mas aquele era diferente dos outros, e isso era visível pela qualidade das respostas, e o comprometimento dos membros em ajudar os outros. Aquele me parecia realmente uma comunidade. Acabei por me registrar, e aí foi...

Hoje estou quase começando no meu terceiro mês de emprego, e já aprendi muito, muito mais do que imaginei. E posso afirmar que muitos desses aprendizados aconteceram aqui, no SOpt.

Só tenho a agradecer a todos que já me ajudaram, respondendo minhas perguntas (que muitas vezes chegavam a ser idiotas) e esclarecendo minhas dúvidas. Se hoje estou aqui, podem ter certeza que muito disso devo a vocês!

Obrigado, e

**Parabéns ao SOpt!**

Answer (score 18):

Eu sempre utilizei o SOen para tudo e mais alguma coisa que tivesse dúvidas. Cheguei ao ponto de não ir sequer ao Google procurar, vinha direto para "cá".

Quando eu descubro, por acaso, ao pesquisar sobre um assunto que existia o SOpt fiquei a pensar para mim "wow agora já posso vir responder a perguntas". Já tinha respondido a algumas no SOen mas não é a mesma coisa.

O meu inicio aqui foi [bem conturbado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157/esclarecer-ou-fazer-o-trabalho-pelos-outros#comment2535_1158). Eu não conhecia de forma nenhuma como funcionava a comunidade, uma vez que o SOen era só base de consulta. Então, estava um bocado em modo agressivo quando entrei aqui, a reclamar com todos que me tentavam guiar ao caminho certo. Felizmente esta comunidade é excelente nesse aspeto, toda a gente me fez ver que não era por esse caminho que eu deveria seguir, sem entrar em conflito comigo, de forma educada.

Eu nessa altura fiquei a pensar, este pessoal é mesmo 5 ✪. E é mesmo, ajudaram-me e guiaram-me para o caminho onde estou agora, sinto-me parte desta comunidade e na "obrigação" de fazer a outros o que me fizeram a mim.

Conheci aqui muita boa gente, não pessoalmente, mas sei se precisasse de alguma coisa que estivesse ao alcance delas que me iriam ajudar. E adquiri muito conhecimento em muitas áreas distintas no SOpt.

Tem sido um ano excelente de SOpt. Tenho orgulho enorme em andar com a t-shirt (camiseta) na rua e quando me veem perguntar o que é e eu dizer o seu significado.

Que venham muitos mais anos de SOpt, e que estejamos todos aqui para festejar todos os anos!

Viva o SOpt! Viva a língua portuguesa!

Comment: Certa vez procurei uma questão sobre CEP e cai aqui no SOPT, e por incrível que pareca o CEP usado na resposta era da minha rua. Só não sei quem é o vizinho rs.

Comment: Meu inicio também foi 'conturbado' e quando via a polidez nas explicações sentia até vergonha da minha incompreensão. Também conheci um bocado de gente bacana - ainda que virtualmente. Entrar no chat é como a pausa do café. rs

Comment: Isso é TOP, o CEP ser da tua rua :)

Answer (score 15):

O SOpt, pra mim, é um dos melhores sites pra quem é programador ou afins para tirar dúvidas que nos atormentam no nosso dia a dia (que não é fácil).

Já usei um outro, mas me arrependo amargamente. A comunidade não é tão ativa e o pessoal não responde com tanta experiência quanto o pessoal daqui.

Aqui, sinceramente, eu aprendi em um ano (pelo que diz no meu perfil... kkkkk) muito, mas muito mais do que em meus 3 anos na faculdade. Uma comunidade tão ativa como a que temos aqui é muito difícil de se achar e principalmente, de se manter.

Queria aqui agradecer a cada um de vocês que me ajudaram em respostas muito completas e cheias de informação que me fizeram crescer mais na minha carreira. Um relato aqui: foi através do SOpt que eu consegui criar um sistema e vendê-lo! Aaah, muito obrigado.

Descobri o SOpt muito por acaso. Em um dia de muita dor de cabeça, tentando resolver um problema que estava tendo, encontrei o SOpt. No começo achei que era brincadeira, que não seria nada sério. Até porque, o SOus era uma fonte de muitas respostas a erros e bugs que nos atormentam! Entrei no site e vi que era verdade, a pura verdade. E desde o dia que entrei, me encantei com a disponibilidade e excelência com que a comunidade se dispôs.

Aqui ajudei algumas pessoas, mas aprendi muito mais do que ensinei.

VOCÊS SÃO DEMAIS!

E mais uma vez, muito obrigado a todos que se dispuseram a me ajudar e a todos que perguntam aqui e através de perguntas de terceiros, nos ensinam muito.

Comment: Agora manda o link do sistema pra eu dar uma brincada ;)

Comment: Haha mando sim @CiganoMorrisonMendez. Você foi uma das pessoas que mais me ajudaram. Achei que nem ia lembrar! kkk. Enfim, é só [clicar aqui](http://sisgal.somee.com). Qualquer coisa só falar comigo que mando os usuários pra você dar uma olhada melhor!

Answer (score 7):

Eu estava pensando em fazer uma pergunta do tipo "O SO ajudou na sua carreira?", mas nem sabia se isso seria um *off-topic*, mas procurando achei essa pergunta no Meta com ótimas respostas, que já respondem a minha pergunta.

Aproveitando para compartilhar um pouco com vocês, há uns 3 anos atrás eu pensei em começar a participar da comunidade, inicialmente no SO em inglês, afinal, é uma filosofia meio *torrent*, não adianta ficar só de *leech*, vamos compartilhar também :)

Ai juntei isso à ideia de que poderia ser bom para a minha carreira. Aqui no Brasil, principalmente à época, não eram muitas empresas que davam importância pra sua presença na rede (SO, Codeplex, Github, CodeProject, etc), parecia que ainda o que valia era uma certificação (embora depois de gente que nunca desenvolveu, baixou as perguntas e tirou *n* certificações, isso diminuiu um pouco), mas fora do Brasil era diferente, e isso também estava mudando por aqui, daí resolvi começar a participar.

Mais tarde comecei a participar por aqui no SO em Português também, e acho aqui uma comunidade muito mais simpática e menos "hostil" que o SO em Inglês, por lá a pergunta tem 2 minutos de vida e já tem 10 *downvotes*, além de outras coisas, e também é super disputado pra se conseguir responder alguma coisa por lá.

Quero dizer que é bom participar, você sempre aprende com o que pergunta, com o que responde, relembra, se recicla quanto ao conhecimento e por ai vai. Isso é uma comunidade diferente de um fórum, como já foi muito comentando por aqui, e é um pouco difícil no começo entender como funciona, mas gosto bastante.

Finalmente, com relação ao escopo da pergunta, ainda não tenho um relato efetivo pra compartilhar, mas posso dizer que é possível perceber que o SO te ajuda sim, seu próprio conhecimento, *networking*, e sua imagem na rede e para o mercado. O SO é visto com muito bons olhos pelo mercado, afinal, onde você recorre quando tem aquela dúvida numa sintaxe ou num problema? ;)

Comment: Você é brasileiro? :-o Quando eu lia as suas publicações, eu jurava que sua escolha léxica era mais semelhante à dos portugueses... Tá aí, uma prova de que mesmo passivamente você acaba criando um _networking_ aqui na comunidade. Acho que interagimos pouco, mas já conheço sua escrita

Comment: Pois é, ou "pt-BR" de São Paulo :)
É que tem algumas coisa que soam bem pra ambos como "assim sendo", "pronto" e "tens que", e é bom usar outros vocabulários. Aliás, até o "nós" tem sumido do vocabulário no Brasil, foi quase que totalmente substituído pelo "a gente" :(

Comment: Aos poucos vamos conhecendo as outras pessoas aqui