# Significado da palavra meta

Tags: suporte, meta

Porque é StackOverflow **"Meta"**?

Eu li a respeito em [Why is “meta” pronounced differently to “beta”?](http://%20https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/247240/why-is-meta-pronounced-differently-to-beta/247241#247241) e fiquei na dúvida se tem alguma relação com beta, ou não. Meu inglês é fraco, então perdoem. Mas acho que é uma pergunta pertinente para que eu possa entender melhor o funcionamento do site por completo, mais uma vez desculpem-me se é uma pergunta tão básica.

Comment: Não é uma pergunta assim tão básica, eu por exemplo descobri os sites "metas" da _pior_ forma: criando uma meta pergunta no site principal e tendo ela migrada para o meta logo em seguida. Só de você saber que temos o Meta e participar dele já diria que é um comportamento relativamente avançado :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Metadados significa dados sobre os dados. Como pode-se ver na [descrição da Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadados).

O nosso site Meta é um site de Perguntas e Respostas sobre o nosso site de Perguntas e Respostas. Deu para entender?

Aqui nós discutimos as regras e conduta do site principal, sempre que temos uma dúvida recorremos aqui.

Já o termo "Beta" se refere à uma das etapas da fase de testes em projetos de desenvolvimentos de software, coincidentemente (ou não), calhou de usarmos os dois termos para referenciarem os nosso sites e esse termos "rimarem", criando muitas vezes uma certa confusão na cabeça do povo.

Mas a fase do Beta do nosso site principal, por exemplo, já ficou para trás, conforme podemos confirmar através da publicação do Gabe:

[Parabéns! Congratulações! Amplexos generalizados!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3757/3117)

Significa que não somos mais um teste e estamos prontos para conquistarmos o mundo \o/. Entretanto o Meta continuará sendo Meta para sempre.

Answer (score 5):

Podemos utilizar a definição da Wikipedia para [Metalinguagem](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalinguagem):

> Em Lógica e Linguística, uma “metal” é uma linguagem usada para
>   descrever algo sobre outra(s) linguagens (linguagens objeto)... De
>   modo mais amplo, uma metalinguagem pode referir-se a qualquer
>   terminologia ou linguagem usada para descrever uma linguagem em si
>   mesma

O prefixo meta é utilizado, então, neste sentido da metalinguagem. De fato, a Wikipedia em inglês tem uma página chamada [Meta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta), que diz (tradução livre):

> Meta (da preposição e do prefixo Grego meta- (μετά-) que significa
>   "depois", ou "alem") é um prefixo utilizado em *Inglês* para indicar
>   um conceito que é uma abstração de outro conceito, utilizado para
>   completa-lo ou complementa-lo.

O uso aqui já foi bem explicado pelo @Math. Outros exemplos de coisas "Meta" são um personagem de filme assitindo a um filme, um texto escrito sobre como escrever bem, etc.

De bônus, uma lista de páginas da Wikipedia em inglês que começam com [Meta-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:PrefixIndex/Meta), incluindo a [Meta Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Meta-Wikipedia).