# Por que "Stack Overflow em Português Meta" e não "Meta Stack Overflow em Português"?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-recusado

Eu sei que parece uma questão um tanto quanto "banal", mas a questão é que as vezes na pressa em rápida visualização procuramos a palavra "meta", todas a outras que participamos o "meta" vem na frente, o que do meu ponto de vista ajuda a diferenciar o meta do site principal. Já no *StackOverflow em Português* a palavra *Meta* vem depois.

A principio isto parece não incomodar, porém quando vou acessar o menu do StackExchange (no topo de todas comunidades) acabo ao menos uma por dia clicando ou no *meta* de outro site/comunidade que fica *antes* ou *depois* na lista de comunidades (sua comunidades) e as vezes clico no site principal do *StackOverflow em Português*.

Talvez seja falta de atenção minha, mas eu realmente acho que na correria o melhor seria mudar para **Meta Stack Overflow em Português**

Note que o logo do *meta.stackOverflow.com* é este:

[image: logo do stackoverflow meta]

Mas o título (tanto do link no menu quanto na tag `<title>`) aparece como `Meta Stack Overflow`.

Poderíamos "padronizar" isto?

> Nota conforme a ótima [resposta do @Molx](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3946/3635) explica o porque "Stack Overflow em Português Meta", mas a minha sugestão seria para facilitar a leitura e evitar se confundir entre as comunidades no menu.

Comment: Se concorda, por favor colabore votando: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258815/198279

Comment: Guilherme, você poderia corrigir meu nick no seu quote? @Molex é muito feio, haha.

Comment: Pra mim fica claro quando penso que "em português" não é um adjetivo mas parte do nome do sujeito, enquanto "META" é  um adjetivo

Comment: @jean entendo, mas veja os exemplo do http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3936/por-que-stack-overflow-em-português-meta-e-não-meta-stack-overflow-em-portugu#comment10535_3946

Answer (score 7):

Acho que a resposta aqui não é uma questão de preferência ou escolha, e sim de características diferentes dos idiomas em questão (Português e Inglês), sendo que isso fica mascarado em virtude da palavra *Meta* não ser tão comum em nosso dia a dia (em ambos idiomas).

Vou evitar exagerar nas definições gramaticais (pra não passar vergonha) e de antemão já peço desculpa se estiver fazendo alguma confusão.

Enfim, a definição do termo *Meta* já foi feita [no contexto do SOpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3780/significado-da-palavra-meta). Um detalhe que não existe lá é que a palavra, no sentido que utilizamos, [tem papel de Adjetivo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meta#English) (em inglês, não há classificação nesse contexto para a língua portuguesa no Wikicionário). O *Meta* é, de certa forma, uma característica do SOpt regular. Se você aceitar isso como verdade, e estou falando assim porque eu mesmo não estou 100% confiante, fica mais fácil entender porque o nome "correto" é **Stack Overflow em Português Meta**. Para tanto, podemos usar exemplos básicos de pequenas frases com adjetivos:

- The beautiful girl.
- A very good joke.
- This is a poorly-formatted question.

Em português, teríamos

- A garota bonita.
- Uma piada muito boa.
- Isso é uma pergunta mal formatada.

Agora, vamos tentar um exemplo mais real. E se ao invés de *Meta*, a palavra fosse *Interno* / *Internal*? Acho que é fácil aceitar que teríamos os sites

- Internal Stack Overflow (*Em inglês*)
- Stack Overflow em Português Interno (*Em português*)

De forma geral (bem geral!), em inglês os adjetivos vêm antes do substantivo a que se referem (em especial em frases simples), enquanto em português vêm depois (mas é comum ser diferente, por exemplo: *A bela garota*). De fato, em muitos casos as duas formas existem, nos dois idiomas, muitas vezes modificando o sentido da frase. Salvo engano, em Portugal é mais comum utilizarem a construção como no inglês, o que de certa forma invalida todo esse argumento.

Outro argumento a favor da versão atual, bem mais simples, é que no início do nome, *Meta* pode soar como uma forma do verbo *Meter*, o que leva a um significado bem estranho...

**Conclusão**

A palavra *Meta*, por ser incomum em nossa fala, não soa errado na forma igual à do inglês, mas a forma atual respeita o que parecer ser correto gramaticalmente. Mas não custa repetir: não sou especialista em idiomas, então posso estar falando abobrinha.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, sim o motivo eu entendo, tanto que estou bastante familiarizado com o inglês, a questão realmente é uma sugestão para facilitar a leitura e evitar se confundir.

Comment: Excelente resposta já fizeste o commit aqui http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language

Comment: Acho que você tem razão, em termos gramaticais. Porém, também existem argumentos a favor do contrário, na própria língua. Por exemplo, o português é bem flexível, e o adjetivo pode muito bem vir antes do substantivo, como em *a bela garota*. Além disso, pesa o fato de que na composição de palavras *meta* é sempre um prefixo, nunca um sufixo (*metalinguagem*, *metáfora*, *metástase*, *metafísica*, etc.) Mas o grande argumento a favor da sugestão do Guilherme não é gramatical, é estilístico: *Meta* na frente (sem duplo sentido, hehe) dá mais ênfase à palavra "meta".

Comment: *Meta pode soar como uma forma do verbo Meter* eu acho que em qualquer posição da palavra na sentença *Meta* pode soa como uma coisa estranha, vai do conhecimento do uso da palavra, se for por causa disto, então hoje podemos ler isto: "StackOverflow em Portugues Meta os pés na estrada" -- para não usar um exemplo pior... concordo com o @bfavaretto sobre os sulfixos... e o seu exemplo "bela garota" é mais comum do que se imagina.

Comment: @bfavaretto Concordo plenamente. Não sei dizer se a forma proposta estaria errada gramaticalmente, mas a resposta teve como objetivo demonstrar o (possível) motivo pela forma atual. Se houver uma certeza de que a mudança não seria errada, em termos de gramática, não vejo problema em fazê-la (e até acho uma boa sugestão). Por outro lado, acho que não é bom mudarmos só para ficar mais bonito e parecido com os outros, caso a nova forma seja incorreta. Seria uma boa pergunta para o Portuguese Language responder...

Comment: @Molx não é para ficar mais bonito ou para parecer com outros, é apenas uma questão de tornar a palavra "meta" mais visivel, facilitando assim a leitura :)