# Qual é a idade real do StackOverflow em Russo?

Tags: debate, stackoverflow

De acordo com o Gabe, no tópico [Parabéns! Congratulações! Amplexos generalizados!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3757/3117):

> É hora de, orgulhosamente, graduar o SOpt como o primeiro site Stack Overflow internacional

Daí eu vi que existe o SO em Russo, que [na Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian) informa que ele está com 68 dias de vida, mas na [página de reputação](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) dos usuários tem vários com mais de 20k de reputação e alguns beirando os 50k.

Ao ver o perfil deles, pode-se ver que vários possuem mais de 4 anos de SORU. Como por exemplo esse [senhor aqui](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232/avp).

Afinal de contas, qual é a idade real do SORU? E somos ou não o primeiro SO internacional?

PS: Perguntei aqui pois não me viro muito bem com russo.

Comment: Russos são quase asiáticos. Tenha isso em mente. Não duvide de nada.

Comment: Bem que falaram que na Russia é tudo invertido, o SO não foi uma exceção, rs.. Exemplos: [1](https://nouniversoparalelo.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/demotivational-reversal.jpg?w=652), [2](http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m96w9zfbwG1qlxohso1_500.jpg), [3](http://cotovelodeformiga.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/russia-sovi%C3%A9tica.jpg) e [4](http://leiaabula.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/gato_peixeiro.jpg).

Comment: 2.2k de users tem a medalha de [aniversariante](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling).

Comment: Na verdade a maioria dos Russos realmente **SÃO** asiáticos :)

Comment: Listando as perguntas do SOru, achei [algumas de 2011](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1811/hello-world-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-main). Segundo fontes não reveladas, parece que, ao lançar o SOru, a KGB em parceria com a equipe de P&D da StackExchange usou algum dispositivo temporal, semelhante a uma máquina do tempo, e enviou alguns russos para o passado com o objetivo de gerar conteúdo e fazer com que o site seja o maior da rede antes mesmo do seu lançamento.

Comment: Outra coisa leve em consideração que existe o private beta e o public beta. Eu não sei quanto tempo eles ficaram no private, mas isto pode ser o motivo da quantidade de dias (: -- Na russia não é você que usa o StackOverflow, lá é o StackOverflow que te usa rs.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento 68 dias é o total da vida dele.

Comment: @utluiz legal seria encontrar umas perguntas de 4 anos atrás sobre Java 8, C++14, Windows 10, navegador Edge e Android Lollipop :P

Comment: Relevante: [Welcome, Nicolas Chabanovsky and Stack Overflow in Russian!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/06/welcome-nicolas-chabanovsky-and-stack-overflow-in-russian/)

Comment: Só sei que eles tem vários clones do [bigown](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jwjLb.png) por lá...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Eu não posso confirmar, nem negar, que o comentário do @utluiz esteja certo.

Diferente do SOpt e SOjp (porque SOja é esquisito), o SOru não veio do "nada". O [Nicolas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/17539/nicolas-chabanovsky), CM de lá, era administrador do Hashcode.ru, um clone russo do Stack Overflow. Então, ao invés de começar o site partindo do 0, o Stack Overflow em Russo importou todo (ou quase todo) o conteúdo do Hashcode, pra manter a comunidade ao invés de quebrá-la.

O conteúdo e a reputação foram mantidas e o SOru, apesar de mais novo que o SOpt, tem conteúdo mais antigo.

Pensem assim: Nós somos os primeiros, mas não os mais antigos.
Agora boa sorte tentando entender.

Comment: Muito estranho isso, não fazia ideia que a SE fizesse esse tipo de coisas.

Comment: Nossa você é bastante informado, eu acho que pouco saberiam disto

Comment: Ok, ainda somos os primeiros :D

Comment: @Math "Primeiro" é o tipo de status que é difícil de perder ; )

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento É fácil saber dessas coisas quando você faz parte da equipe que decide essas coisas :D

Comment: Entendo, que bom então. Então você é um tipo de James Bond que está espionando a KGB... ops quero dizer o SOru? :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ou um Max von Stierlitz, espionando o SOpt

Comment: @Gabe não sei se ele conseguiria um cargo tão alto assim logo de começo rs. Se bem que se tratando dos russos seria possivel rs

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento O importante é continuar confundindo todo mundo, pra não ser descoberto pra quem eu trabalho de verdade!

Comment: последние будут первыми