# O que é a eleição? Como ela funciona?

Tags: debate, faq, eleição

O quadro de avisos diz que começaram as eleições para moderadores.

Como funciona a eleição, e como eu posso participar?

> [image: quadro de avisos]

[Retornar ao FAQ da Comunidade](/q/699)

Answer (score 25):

A comunidade está elegendo [seus moderadores ♦](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators); são as pessoas responsáveis por moderar o site.

O período de eleição tem 3 fases diferentes:

### 1ª Fase: Candidatura

#### Duração: 7 dias

Qualquer pessoa pode se candidatar à moderador, desde que tenha mais de 300 pontos de reputação. Isso é uma forma de garantir que os candidatos tenham um mínimo de familiaridade com o site.

As candidaturas não são definitivas e os candidatos podem se retirar da corrida a qualquer momento. A lista de candidaturas é ordenada como uma pilha, com as candidaturas mais antigas no final da página.

Cada candidato deve se apresentar e explicar por que acreditam que seriam bons moderadores. Qualquer pessoa pode comentar nestes posts, e esses comentários não podem receber votos ou ser sinalizados (para avisar a equipe do SE sobre qualquer problema, use a sala de chat especial para a eleição).

<kbd>[image: candidatura]</kbd>

Após 7 dias, os 30 candidatos com mais reputação avançam para as *primárias*. Caso tenhamos menos que 10 candidaturas, a eleição avança direto para a fase final.

### 2ª Fase: Primárias

#### Duração: 4 dias

É quando a votação tem início. Qualquer membro da comunidade com mais de 150 pontos de reputação pode votar, mas candidatos não podem votar em si próprios. Você pode votar uma vez em cada candidato, como numa pergunta ou resposta no site. Não são permitidos comentários.

É possível votar a favor ou contra um candidato, usando as setas ao lado de cada candidatura. Um voto a favor indica que você gostaria que essa candidata passasse para a próxima fase. O voto contra representa o oposto.

<kbd>[image: primárias]</kbd>

Os candidatos são listados em ordem aleatória e, assim como antes, qualquer candidato pode abandonar sua candidatura se assim desejar.

O número de votos para cada candidato é público, assim você pode ter uma boa noção de quem são os candidatos mais bem vistos pela comunidade.

Depois de 4 dias, os 10 candidatos com mais votos passam para a fase de *eleição*.

### 3ª Fase: Eleição

#### Duração: 4 dias

É a última fase da eleição e, assim como nas primárias, qualquer usuário com mais de 150 pontos de reputação pode votar. Além disso, diferentemente da etapa anterior, candidatos podem votar em si próprios. Comentários não são permitidos e os candidatos são listados aleatoriamente.

Cada pessoa tem direito a 3 votos: sua 1ª, 2ª e 3ª escolhas para moderador. Os votos são contabilizados usando o [Método VUT](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/how-are-moderator-election-votes-counted-in-plain-english).

<kbd>[image: eleição]</kbd>

Diferente das primárias, o número de votos de cada candidato não é público.

### Resultados e outras informações:

A [página de eleições](http://elections.stackexchange.com/), criada por [Yi Jiang](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150097), contém as estatísticas e resultados de todas as eleições nos sites do Stack Exchange.

Informações sobre eleições anteriores estão disponíveis em  [pt.stackoverflow.com/election](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election).

Durante uma eleição, essa página não lista os resultados anteriores, mas eles continuam disponíveis em `pt.stackoverflow.com/election/<nº da eleição>`. Por exemplo, o resultado da nossa primeira eleição estará disponível em [pt.stackoverflow.com/election/1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/1). Se nenhuma eleição estiver ocorrendo, o resultado de todas as eleições até então estará em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election.

Você pode ver a lista de moderadores atuais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators).

Comment: Nota: quem copiar o texto de exemplo do Gabe na sua "declaração de candidatura" (ou seja lá qual for o nome disso) será automaticamente desclassificado. (Mentira, mas se alguém fizer isso, eu faço campanha contra).

Comment: @bfavaretto De acordo plenamente! Eu fiz questão de fazer o texto mais genérico possível pra ver se ninguém se engraçava! Além disso, tem um erro de Português, pra gente poder saber se alguém só copiou mesmo!

Comment: Estamos nas primárias. Os 10 candidatos com mais votos passam para a próxima fase (e os demais são eliminados), até aqui ok. E se dentre estes 10 primeiros, os últimos deles (ex: o nono e o décimo) tiverem votação negativa (assim como o décimo-primeiro em diante), eles passam para a próxima fase mesmo assim?

Comment: Em caso de eleições com 2 candidatos, na terceira fase também são permitidos 3 votos?

Comment: @Math. Sim, é permitido. Já votei em eleições de outros sites da rede com duas vagas disponíveis e você pode dar três votos mesmo assim. Entretanto, devido ao funcionamento do algoritmo Meek que é usado na eleição, o seu terceiro voto só será considerado (possivelmente de forma fracionária apenas) em rounds posteriores onde pelo menos um dos seus dois primeiros candidatos for eleito ou for eliminado sem que o terceiro o tenha sido ainda e sem que as duas vagas já tenham sido preenchidas.

Comment: Se é possível votar contra e a favor, uma pessoa pode gerar 2 votos para o candidato (1 para ele e -1 para todos os outros). Essa é a intenção? Não seria mais correto ter apenas votos positivos?

Comment: @Fabiano Bem, na etapa das primárias (que já passou) você pode/podia votar positivo ou negativo em cada candidato independente dos demais. O objetivo é/era reduzir a lista de candidatos para 10 ou menos candidatos, sendo estes os 10 mais aceitos. Nesta eleição havia 13 candidatos, então 3 seriam eliminados nas primárias. Entretanto, como 3 candidatos desistiram durante as primárias, acabou que essa etapa não eliminou ninguém diretamente/automaticamente. Na fase final (que é agora), você vota nos três candidatos que você mais gosta, não há voto negativo nesta última etapa.