# Seria útil adicionar um link de FAQ nesta página de Eleições para Moderador?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, eleição

"Caí aqui de paraquedas" e senti muito a falta de um link para uma página de FAQ nesta página de Eleições para Moderador do Stack Exchange. Me senti um pouco perdido.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election

Não seria útil adicionar um link para esta página de FAQ ou para alguma outra página neste sentido?

["O que é a eleição? Como ela funciona?"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3882/o-que-%C3%A9-a-elei%C3%A7%C3%A3o-como-ela-funciona)

Comment: *Necessidade* é uma palavra forte, mas acho que seria útil dar destaque às principais perguntas ao invés de colocar apenas o link para a tag [eleição]. A verdade é que o texto da página está todo sem destaque e fica até chato de ler por isso, o do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/election/12) parece mais interessante e pode servir como base para comparação caso venham a modificar o nosso :)

Comment: @RafaelTavares entendo. Mas poderia adicionar um subtítulo semelhante ao "Additional Links:" com um link para esta página ["O que é a eleição? Como ela funciona?"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3882/o-que-%C3%A9-a-elei%C3%A7%C3%A3o-como-ela-funciona). Não é mesmo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pronto, feito! Fica melhor assim.

Comment: Obrigado @Maniero! 