# Já acabaram as eleições?

Tags: suporte

Apareceu uma mensagem:

> A eleição do moderador da comunidade Stack Overflow em Português 2015 está em andamento — indicações agora estão sendo recebidas.

Porém eu clico no link e informa:

> #### Eleições para moderador da comunidade
>
> ---
>
> Não há eleição ativa para moderador da comunidade no momento.

Já acabaram?

Nem tive a chance de votar... :(

Comment: Você estava concorrendo? :P

Comment: Acho que não. Se ninguém me indicou... O que acredito que não... Mas eu não deveria ter votado?

Comment: Foi uma piada, porque seu título fala: "Perdi as eleições?". Mas isso com certeza se trata de um bug.

Comment: uehuehu, eu pensei nisso... Mas a culpa é do português e não minha... :P auehuahe

Comment: Coloco tag [tag:bug] ?

Comment: @Math tu dum tss :)

Comment: Uns minutos atrás tinha um texto e links na página da eleição.

Comment: Primeiro de abr... junho!

Comment: E [houve muita gente a ver](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/80/caucus)...  ... e ficar com esperança que seria desta... [como prometido](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3757/129)...

Comment: Poxa vida, agora que vou entrar em depressão mesmo, teve até medalha pra quem votou... :'(

Comment: Essa medalha é para quem visitou a página da eleição e não do voto. [1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fd49.png), [2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3pG3Y.png)

Comment: @KaduAmaral ninguém votou, e não hove eleições. Algo estranho aconteceu e espero uma explicação do Gabe pois [ele apagou o post oficial também](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3843/129)...

Comment: Ah beleza... Coloquei a tag [tag:bug]... :)

Comment: Também recebi a notificação, deve ter sido um teste.

Comment: Agora está aparecendo em destaque http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi3wD.png

Comment: Oh @Gabe que confusão...

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21957220#21957220

Comment: Entrei no meta para abrir a mesma pergunta porque recebi notificação, então quando clico, direciona para uma página "vazia" e fiquei sem entender. Fiz screenshot -> http://s22.postimg.org/6hptmepxr/eleicao_sopt.png

Comment: @JorgeB. o que diz o chat? Estou sem acesso ao chat (proxy corporativo)

Comment: O chat diz `Tem mais algumas eleiçòes correndo, e a gente vai começar a do SOpt semana que vem` - @Gabe

Comment: Quando começar me indiquem, não me importo em ganhar ou perder o importante é a̶t̶r̶a̶p̶a̶l̶h̶a̶r̶ participar :D hehe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ocorreu um ligeiro [SNAFU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_slang#SNAFU), por culpa minha.

Algum tempo atrás nós *planejamos* iniciar a eleição nessa Segunda Feira, dia 01 de Junho. Essa era a ideia, e ela seria revisada antes do dia 01, pra saber se acontecia ou não a eleição. A semana acabou, a programação foi mantida e eu não me lembrei de cancelar na Segunda **antes** de começar. Quando deu 20:00UTC o site iniciou a eleição sozinho, eu cuspi café no monitor, lembrei que ela não devia ter começado ainda e reprogramei pra 1 semana depois.

O motivo do atraso - não só o de anteontem, mas a demora em geral pra começar - é que a eleição envolve traduzir bastante coisa. Muito disso não está no Transifex mas sim no MSE, e infelizmente não pode ser traduzido comunitariamente.
Como um evento que pode - e deve - envolver **toda** a comunidade, ter partes dela disponíveis apenas em Inglês não é aceitável.

Eu sei que "cancelar" a eleição é meio frustrante, e que vocês não veem a hora de ter uma. Mas a eleição é o tipo de coisa que merece ser absolutamente bem feita. É o evento mais importante da comunidade e vale a pena esperar pra ocorrer tudo perfeitamente.

À exceção do início falso eventual :D

Comment: Não seria uma boa remover a eleição dos Próximos eventos?

Comment: @Math é uma das coisas pra hoje

Comment: Será que vamos ganhar outra medalha de "caucus" quando a eleição recomeçar?