# Os destaques sumiram do boletim da comunidade

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro, boletim-da-comunidade

No boletim da comunidade (aquela caixa amarela do lado direito do site), apareciam as perguntas com a tag [destaque](/questions/tagged/destaque) aqui do meta. No momento há duas perguntas com a tag, mas elas não estão listadas ali:

[image]

Talvez a intenção tenha sido [remover o anúncio das eleições](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3844/j%c3%a1-acabaram-as-elei%c3%a7%c3%b5es#comment10141_3856)?

Comment: Caching... both questions are now appearing in the community bulletin

Comment: @Oded when is cache renewed? The post is still there.

Comment: @Sergio - you mean the election notice? Not sure about that.

Comment: @Oded yes, I mean the Election highlight in the toolbar, here in meta and in the main site. It should be removed or go a not-empty page.

Comment: OK, that's gone now. Had to dig a bit for that...